# How do I align my button under my heading, and make the button responsive?

Tags: html, css, button, position

I am trying to put a button under a heading, but the button is being pushed to the side. I assume it has to do with absolute position or something, but I am not too sure. I also want to make the button responsive like the text, so that the size of the button changes in different windows.

HTML:

```css
    body{
      font-family: sans-serif;
      margin:0px;
    }
    .splash{
      background-color: #faead3;
      height: fill;
      padding: 0;
      margin:0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: left; /* align horizontal */
      align-items: center; /* align vertical */
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .splash h1{
      margin:0px;
      font-size: 4.5vw;
      color: #08aabe;
      margin-left: 2.5em;
      padding-bottom: 3.5em;
    }
    .button {
        background-color: #08aabe; 
        border: none;
        color: #faead3;
        padding: 1em 2em;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1w;
    }
```

```html
<div class="splash">
        <h1>Random Text.</h1>
      <a class="button"href="#">Button Link</a>
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qQraNB

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: From what I see, the button is in the center and not to the side

Comment: `font-size: 1w;` in    `.button {` is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `display:flex` whats make them be in same line so:

1.Remove `display:flex` from `.splash`

2.`font-size: 1w;` in `.button {}` is invalid change it to `font-size: 2.5vw;`

3. you can use `margin-left: 4.5em;` to button

[See code in fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/ky256Lpw/)

```css
   body{
      font-family: sans-serif;
      margin:0px;
    }
    .splash{
      background-color: #faead3;
      height: fill;
      padding: 0;
      margin:0;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .splash h1{
      margin:0px;
      font-size: 4.5vw;
      color: #08aabe;
      margin-left: 2.5em;
      padding-bottom: 3.5em;
    }
    .button {
        background-color: #08aabe; 
        border: none;
        color: #faead3;
        padding: 1em 2em;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 2.5vw;
        margin-left: 4.5em;
    }
```

```html
<div class="splash">
     <h1>Random Text.</h1>
      <a class="button"href="#">Button Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a `padding-bottom: 3.5em;` set on the heading title, which is pushing the heading up, if you take that the padding bottom off, the button should align the same vertically on both of them.